# Overriding Abstract in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to override an abstract in Magento but it does not like the info in my config.xml below you will see my folder structure for the abstract I am trying to override and the portion of my config.xml specific to this file.

Original Directory:

`app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php`

My Directory:

`app/code/local/EGeeked/Coupons/Rule/Model/Abstract.php`

My config.xml:

```
<models>
    <EGeeked_Coupons>
        <class>EGeeked_Coupons_Rule_Model_Abstract</class>
    </EGeeked_Coupons>
    <rule>
        <rewrite>
            <model_abstract>EGeeked_Coupons_Rule_Model_Abstract</model_abstract>
        </rewrite>
     </rule>
</models>
```

My extends in the Abstract.php

```
abstract class EGeeked_Coupons_Rule_Model_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, a terminology lesson.  Next, explaining why you can't do that.  Third, an alternate solution that's not ideal but may get you where you need to go.

#### Terminology

From the looks of your question, you're not trying to "override" a class, you're trying to rewrite the class.  A class rewrite is where you add configuration nodes to Magento in order to tell it

> Instantiate this class instead of that class

An "override" is where you copy a class from the Magento core into the local code pool.  In other words, copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

An override is where you tell Magento "use this class file instead of the other class file".  Similar, but different from a rewrite.  Rewrites are considered better practice because they're less destructive, and less likely to cause problems with upgrades and extension compatibility.

#### You can't do that

You can't rewrite an abstract class.  The rewrite system works because Magento uses a factory pattern to instantiate model, blocks, and helpers

```
$class = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

What a rewrite does is, in pseudo code

```
function getModel($model)
{
    if("can I find a rewrite configuration for $model")
    {
        //instantiate the model with the rewrite
    }
    else
    {
        //instantiate the normal model
    }
}
```

Since an abstract class is never instantiated, it can never be rewritten.

#### Solutions

From what I can tell, there's only three classes that inherit from this abstract class in a standard Magento installation.

```
catalogrule/rule
Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule

rule/rule
Rule/Model/Rule.php

salesrule/rule
SalesRule/Model/Rule.php
```

You could add a rewrite for each of these classes individually, ideally putting your new logic in a shared helper class.  You'd need to handle extensions or custom code in a similar way, but it's one possible path forward.

The other alternative is to use a traditional class override and copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

This will let you modify a single `Abstract` class, but you'll need to merge any changes from upgraded versions into this class — and you may cause system problems when (not if) you forget to do that.

Good luck!

Comment: @Alan, somewhere on the blog I read this (not in favor though)

Copy `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` from `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier` to `app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier`, do NOT change the class name, just change or add the methods as you need. This is a trick. Magento loads a class from several locations, and app/code/local comes before app/code/core. Is it a good practice ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy It's common practice -- whether its good practice depends on what sort of time/stability tradeoffs you want to meet (i.e. I don't think it's a good practice, but with budgets as tight as they are on projects people are going to do it)

Answer (score 1):

It's true that one cannot override an abstract class from Mage, but one can override its particular method using custom extension from local mean instead of placing the whole `Abstract.php` in the same location in local. One can override it from local with an own module.

For example, if I need to modify reorder action in Mage which is written in:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Controller\Abstract.php
```

then I can override its controller from my module as below defining it in my `config.xml`:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Sales>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Custom_Sales>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <sales>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <custom_sales before="Mage_Sales">Custom_Sales</custom_sales>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </sales>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

After that add the controller to module:

```
app\code\local\Custom\Sales\controllers\OrderController.php
```

in the following way:

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Sales').DS.'OrderController.php');

class Custom_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Sales_OrderController
{
    public function reorderAction()
    {
        "Add required changes !!";
    }
}
```

All is set to run the abstract method from local module. In a similar way one can override an abstract model method, too.